# Como adicionar dependências via interface web/desktop do GitHub (não-git)?

Tags: github

Como fazer para adicionar dependências (um repositório depende de outro) via interface web/desktop do GitHub?
Claro se houver como, caso não haja resposta especifica para a questão, aceito também métodos alternativos via Git por exemplo.

Ou seja: procuro algo do tipo:

> repositório X depende um repositório Y, esse Y fica em uma pasta Y no diretório padrão que contém X e é atualizado automaticamente.

Creio que é assim o funcionamento das dependências de repositório.

**OBS:** Acesso elas em Graphs-Dependencies no GitHub